# onMessage not triggered in websocketListener android client

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, kotlin, okhttp

I am facing an issue regarding websocket communications. To put you in perspective i have a springboot microservice backend, that i want to connect to an android application.

=> I want to know why the onMessage function in the android websocketListener is not getting triggered

Note that **i CAN send messages in the adequate topics, but i cannot receive them**

---

**In the backend :**

I have a `notification-service` with a websocket url `ws://localhost:8082/notifications-ws`. i have multiple topics, of this format : `/topic/alert/<email>` where email is the email of some users.

Here is the websocket configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        // internal broker to hold the messages
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/alert");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        // STOMP endpoint for websocket client or sockjs if the client does not support websocket
        registry.addEndpoint("/notifications-ws")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
        registry.addEndpoint("/notifications-ws")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }
}
```

The sender code :

```java
@Component
public class WebSocketNotificationSender {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
    private transient final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WebSocketNotificationSender.class);

    public void sendNotification(String email, String message) {
        String destination = "/topic/alert/" + email;
        logger.info("\n>>> Sending to : destination: {}", destination);
        try{
            byte[] byteMessage = message.getBytes();
            messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(destination, byteMessage);
            logger.info("\n>>> Message sent !");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("\n>>> Message not sent !");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**In the frontend :**

I want to connect multiple android applications to one (or multiple) of these topics

Here is the websocket listener code :

```kotlin
class MyWebsocketListener: WebSocketListener() {
    override fun onOpen(webSocket: WebSocket, response: Response) {
        // Connection opened
        Log.d("NotificationWebsocketClient", "Openning Conenction to ${webSocket.request().url()}")
    }

    override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, text: String) {
        // Received a text message
        Log.d("NotificationWebsocketClient", "Received text message: $text")
    }

    override fun onMessage(webSocket: WebSocket, bytes: ByteString) {
        // Received a binary message
        Log.d("NotificationWebsocketClient", "Received bytes message: ${bytes.hex()}")
    }

    override fun onClosing(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
        super.onClosing(webSocket, code, reason)
        // Connection is about to close
        Log.d("NotificationWebsocketClient", "WebSocket closing : " + reason)
    }

    override fun onClosed(webSocket: WebSocket, code: Int, reason: String) {
        super.onClosed(webSocket, code, reason)
        // Connection closed
        Log.d("NotificationWebsocketClient", "WebSocket closed")
    }

    override fun onFailure(webSocket: WebSocket, t: Throwable, response: Response?) {
        super.onFailure(webSocket, t, response)
        val url = webSocket.request().url().toString()
        // Connection failure
        Log.e("NotificationWebsocketClient", "WebSocket $url failure : " + t.message)
    }
}
```

and the okhttp client :

```kotlin
class NotificationWebsocketClient(private val email: String){
    companion object {
        var queueId = 0
    }
    private val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().readTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS).connectTimeout(30,TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()
    private var webSocket: WebSocket? = null
    private val destinationPath = "topic/alert/$email"
    private val websocketEndpoint = "notifications-ws"
    private val websocketUrl = "ws://" + ApiClient.HOSTNAME + ":" + ApiClient.PORT

    suspend fun connect(){
        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url("$websocketUrl/$websocketEndpoint")
            .build()
        webSocket = client.newWebSocket(request, WebsocketListener())
    }

    fun disconnect() {
        webSocket?.close(1000, "Disconnecting")
    }

    /**
     * send message using STOMP protocol
     */
    fun sendMessage(message: String) {
        webSocket?.send(
            "SEND\n" +
            "destination:/$destinationPath\n" +
            "\n" +
            "{\"message\":\"$message\"}\n" +
            "\u0000"
        )
    }

    /**
     * subscribe using STOMP protocol
     */
    fun subscribe() {
        val id = queueId++
        webSocket?.send(
            "SUBSCRIBE\n" +
            "id:sub-"+ id +"\n" +
            "destination:/$destinationPath\n" +
            "\n" +
            "\u0000"
        )
        Log.d("NotificationWebsocketClient", "id:sub-"+ id +" > Subscribed to $destinationPath")
        sendMessage("id:sub-${queueId -1} > Hello $email from Android!")
    }
}
```